# Foreign key problem in ASP.NET MVC using C# when I try to delete a database entry

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, model-view-controller, foreign-keys

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and in general to C#, maybe you can help me.

I have a connection to my database and I already have a controller of the `SEC_Users` table. My problem is that our database has a lot of tables with a lot of foreign keys. So our users are connected to a lot of other tables (project is just a workaround for me to learn).

Now I have the problem that I can't delete the user because he is connected to other tables and I need to delete those entries first. I started to delete one after another table. But now I'm kinda stuck.

The user has some entries in the table `SEC_LoginToken`, which I need to delete. This works, but I also need to delete the entry in the table `SEC_RefreshToken` which is connected with the `SEC_LoginToken` via the column `token`. And I don't know how I can delete those entries in the `SEC_RefreshToken` table.

Sorry for my English, hopefully you understand my problem.

So for deleting all the entries in the other tables, I take the id from the user and see if there's an entry with that userid and if so I delete it. I tried to take the `token` column from `SEC_LoginToken` where I want to delete the rows and save it into a list. And then I want to say that for every entry in the list the row in `SEC_RefreshToken` where the column `token` is the same should be deleted. But it doesn't work. Is there maybe a better way? Or what am I doing wrong?

Here you see the DELETE (function?) of my controller:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    // Löschen aller Einträge des Users in der DAT_UserDetail
    foreach (var ec in db.DAT_UserDetail.Where(x => x.UserID == id))
        db.DAT_UserDetail.Remove(ec);

    // Löschen aller Einträge des Users in der SEC_ObjectAccessRight
    foreach (var ec in db.SEC_ObjectAccessRight.Where(x => x.UserID == id))
        db.SEC_ObjectAccessRight.Remove(ec);

    // Löschen aller Einträge des Users in der SEC_UserGroupFunction_User
    foreach (var ec in db.SEC_UserGroupFunction_User.Where(x => x.UserID == id))
        db.SEC_UserGroupFunction_User.Remove(ec);

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    List<string> token = new List<string>();

    foreach (char ec in db.SEC_LoginToken.Where(x => x.UserID == id)
        .Select(x => x.Token)
        .Single())
        token.Add(ec.ToString());

    foreach (string row in token)
    {
        // db.SEC_RefreshToken.Remove(token);
        db.SEC_RefreshToken.RemoveRange(db.SEC_RefreshToken.Where(x => x.Token == row));
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Löschen aller Einträge des Users in der SEC_LoginToken
    foreach (var ec in db.SEC_LoginToken.Where(x => x.UserID == id))
        db.SEC_LoginToken.Remove(ec);

    // Löschen des Users
    SEC_User sEC_User = db.SEC_User.Find(id);
    db.SEC_User.Remove(sEC_User);

    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I just want to hit the delete Button without getting the error: the sequence contains more than one element. It happens where I coded

```
foreach (char ec in db.SEC_LoginToken.Where(x => x.UserID == id).Select(x => x.Token).Single())
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: use `First()` instead of `Single()`?

Comment: I'd say remove the `Single()` alltogether since you want to iterate over every token of the user and not just one.

Comment: I think you should first delete from the last table or the that does not produce an error then subsequent ones. Also after your foreach loops you may need to save changes before you proceed to another loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error '*the sequence contains more than one element*' happens because

```
db.SEC_LoginToken.Where(x => x.UserID == id).Select(x => x.Token).Single()
```

returns more than one element. In this case that means that there is a `Collection` of `SEC_LoginToken` for `x.UserID == id`. You should change it to:

```
foreach (string ec in db.SEC_LoginToken.Where(x => x.UserID == id)
            .Select(x => x.Token)
            .ToList())
```

In other note, have you consider using a logical/soft delete? That would solve all your cascading delete problems and you would have history for auditing.

Comment: Hi Leandro,

thanks a lot for your response! Now I understand my problem, I changed to foreach loop as you did and needed to change the type of the list and now it works.

And also thank you for mentioning "logical/soft delete". I haven´t heard about it before, but I will check it out!

Best regards